# How to group an array of nested objects by three different properties in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, group-by, ramda.js

I have an array of objects looking like this

```
[
 {store: {id: "1", metadata: {itemName: "Q", itemCode: "332", itemDueDate: "2021-10-28", …}}},
 {store: {id: "2", metadata: {itemName: "WA", itemCode: "190", itemDueDate: "2021-08-23", …}}},
 {store: {id: "3", metadata: {itemName: "P", itemCode: "199", itemDueDate: "2020-12-03", …}}}
]
```

How can I group this array by using three different properties from the metadata object, so it would be a combination of:

1. itemName
2. itemCode
3. itemDueDate

I tried using Ramda's GroupWith, but i just found out that they use consecutive order when grouping.

```
export const groupedItems = (items: ArchiveItems) => R.groupWith<ArchiveItems>((a, b) => {
return a.store.metadata.itemName === b.store.metadata.itemName &&
       a.store.metadata.itemCode === b.store.metadata.itemCode &&
       a.store.metadata.itemDueDate === b.store.metadata.itemDueDate
})(items)
```

Comment: your arrays are invalid , you can't assign indexes like that , paste full code and check for syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ramda's [`groupWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith) is designed for grouping consecutive elements.  [`groupBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) is what you probably want.  It takes a function which converts your object into a string and then groups your array into an object with an array for each converted string. 
 You can choose to create that string however you like, most commonly by extracting a single property.  Here we could combine multiple properties into a string:

```js
const collect = pipe (
  groupBy (({store: {metadata: m}}) => `${m.itemName}~${m.itemCode}~${m.itemDueDate}`),
  values
)

const data = [{store: {id: "1", metadata: {itemName: "Q", itemCode: "332", itemDueDate: "2021-10-28", foo: "a"}}}, {store: {id: "2", metadata: {itemName: "WA", itemCode: "190", itemDueDate: "2021-08-23", foo: "b"}}}, {store: {id: "3", metadata: {itemName: "P", itemCode: "199", itemDueDate: "2020-12-03", foo: "c"}}}, {store: {id: "4", metadata: {itemName: "WA", itemCode: "190", itemDueDate: "2021-08-23", foo: "d"}}}, {store: {id: "5", metadata: {itemName: "P", itemCode: "199", itemDueDate: "2020-12-03", foo: "e"}}}, {store: {id: "6", metadata: {itemName: "WA", itemCode: "190", itemDueDate: "2021-08-23", foo: "f"}}}]

console .log (
  collect (data)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, values} = R                           </script>
```

I made a guess here about your actual structure, as what you've posted is not legal JS.  I also added additional items, as we want to demonstrate what happens when there are actual duplicates.

Note that the `values` call at the end turns this into an array of arrays.  You could keep the original object, but I imagine keys like `"P~199~2020-12-03"` wouldn't likely be very helpful.  Or you might have to do further processing to achieve your underlying goal.

If some of your values could possibly include a `~`, you might need a different separator.

Comment: Thanks Scott! It works properly! I do have one more unresolved question here...

Sometimes i might miss the metadata for some product ex:
`[{store: {id: "1", metadata: {}, foo:"a" }}]`
And in this case I'd like to group those items by `foo` which is outside the metadata. How can i implement this in the collect function?

P.S. Sorry for writing my own representation of the array of objects instead of a proper JS, but anyways you've guessed it right!

Comment: @Chulsy: I might try something like this: `groupBy (({store: {metadata: m, foo}}) => m ? \`${m.itemName}~${m.itemCode}~${m.itemDueDate}\` : \`~~${foo}\`)`.  You mostly need to ensure that the two different key formats cannot collide.

Comment: That's what i needed! Thank you once again, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Might try a reduce function

```
    const l: ArchiveItems[] = [
    {id: "1", metadata: {itemName: "Q", itemCode: "332", itemDueDate: "2021-10-28"}},
    {id: "2", metadata: {itemName: "WA", itemCode: "190", itemDueDate: "2021-08-23"}},
    {id: "3", metadata: {itemName: "P", itemCode: "199", itemDueDate: "2020-12-03"}}
];

const result = l.reduce<Map<string, ArchiveItems[]>>((acc, cv) => {
    const cvKey = `${cv.metadata.itemName}_${cv.metadata.itemCode}_${cv.metadata.itemDueDate}`;
    if (acc.get(cvKey) !== undefined) {
        acc.set(cvKey, [...acc.get(cvKey), cv])
    } else {
        acc.set(cvKey, [cv])
    }
    return acc;
}, new Map());
```